# Why am I unable to see my photos on my laptop?

Tags: nikon, file-transfer

I recently got a Nikon D3100 and, after trying it out, I went to upload the photos to my laptop. In doing so it asked me to download Nikon's version of Windows Photo Gallery, but now I am not able to view my photos. Is there anything I can do to resolve this?

Comment: More information would be useful - what version of windows are you using, are you trying to view raw or JPEGs etc

Comment: Some info that would help - what did you actually install: was it [Nikon ViewNX](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/software/viewnx2/) or was it the [Microsoft Codec Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26829) for example?  Include the link to where you got the software from if you can.  What version of windows do you have?

Comment: When I first put my SD card into my laptop it asked me to install the Nikon ViewNX I think, and how when I  go to look at my photos it just constantly says 'Loading'

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you were shooting RAW images.  These types of files are not directly viewable without special software that understands how your camera works and how to interpret the data from the sensor.  They offer a lot of strengths over JPEG, such as being able to adjust white balance and recover from some over or under-exposure much more easily, however the cost is that you need to use the special software to read them, finish your post production and then export to JPEG or similar image formats so that they can be read on other computers.

You need to actually use the software you installed to view them.  You should be able to launch ViewNX or you can try a third party tool such as DarkTable to work with the images.  You can find more information on the benefits of RAW files [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2627/good-examples-of-raws-advantages-over-jpeg).

As Stan Rogers pointed out, there are also tools available to allow explorer to view thumbnails of the images, but it sounds like you don't have any of those currently installed.

Comment: For Windows, at least, both Nikon (Nikon-only) and Microsoft (more comprehensive, but not always as up-to-date) offer codecs for use with Windows Explorer's tiles/thumbnails views and Windows Photo Viewer. You still need other raw-compatible software to do anything *useful* with the images, but at least you can tell which is which (in Explorer and the file-open dialogs) with the viewing codec.

Comment: @StanRogers - excellent point.  I always forget about those since I don't use Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything i can do to resolve this?

**Perhaps downloading a free photo manager/organizer/viewer would help?**

I would recommend [XnView MP](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/) if you're on the cutting edge or XnView Classic if you're more conservative.

Install & run it (don't forget to associate the image files - it is easy, the program asks for this).