# Shooting on NEF is making my photos turn out differently in bridge vs my camera

Tags: nikon, lightroom, raw, adobe-bridge

I usually shot on JPG until a friend told me to shoot on NEF the other day. Ever since all my photos have been screwing up in bridge or lightroom. They look normal and good on my camera screen, but when I go in to edit they appear saturated, almost darker, and the white balance is messed up. I have been a photographer for less than a year so I'm not highly experienced. I would like to know if anyone else has had this problem, or knows how to fix it??

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24940/raw-versus-jpg-images-with-a-dslr

Comment: With Nikon cameras, you can save both, NEF and JPG. So, as a beginner, you can experiment with post-processing without losing the comfort of out-of-camera JPGs.

Comment: It depends what you open it in. Only Nikon software can properly match the initial RAW interpretation to that of the embedded jpg. See https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/96952/why-does-the-histogram-of-an-image-depends-on-the-software-that-opened-it/96953#96953 Practically, this means not using an Adobe workflow right through - use Nikon NX Studio initially, then export 16-bit TIFF to Adobe.

Comment: NEF files don't have white balance applied yet. Nikon software knows the camera settings, so it can and will apply them if you open a NEF file. I can recommend it for starting with RAW, and it is free. I use it because I don't want to keep jpg files too but like to set most things in camera.

Comment: Related: [Opening NEF files on windows initially open fine but then change contrast](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/104573/15871) and [Are paler raw images normal for a newer sensor with higher dynamic range?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/98368/15871) and [While shooting in RAW, do you have to post-process it to make the picture look good?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/76351/15871)