# How can I adjust the RAW (DNG) files from my FIMI X8 SE 2020 drone to achieve colors similar to the default JPG files?

Tags: photo-editing, image-processing, darktable, aerial-photography

I got a FIMI X8 SE 2020 drone a couple years ago, which has a good quality camera. However, when I shoot in RAW+JPG mode, I notice that the RAW (DNG) files have dull and distorted colors compared to the default JPG files when opened in darktable (I know that this is normal, but in my case it seems to me that they are actually very distorted). I have tried adjusting the images in darktable, but no matter how many adjustments I apply or how many tutorials I follow, I have not been able to achieve a result better, or even comparable to the default JPG file. I have achieved good results using darktable to develop RAW photos from other sources, such as the Canon EOS T5 reflex camera, so I suspect that this may be because darktable does not have the correct tone curve profile for the camera of my drone.

I have attached two image files for reference: a screenshot of the RAW image as it is displayed on darktable and a screenshot of the corresponding default JPG image. You can download the files using the links below:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kAELHIVECtjiN8O-0yzSKwhZLOQyKdJ1/view?usp=share_link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FLsumLshr6pfhmGyTGwFPjpaqxmcR2Cb/view?usp=share_link

The actual RAW file can be found in the next link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xNdEs6wUhWojkfXPDaw29iZcL3j29FkB/view?usp=share_link

I would like to know if there are any specific adjustments or techniques that I can use to improve the color accuracy and quality of my RAW (DNG) files. Are there any alternative RAW development software that have a tone curve profile for my drone's camera? Or are there any general tips or guidelines that I should follow when editing RAW files from a drone camera?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Raw versus JPG Images with a DSLR](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24940/raw-versus-jpg-images-with-a-dslr)  Do not be misleaded by word DSLR.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But it doesn't solve my question. I'm familiar with RAW development, I have done it with my DSLR camera for the last 8 years. The problem I have with the images of my drone is that I don't have a recognizable starting point, and I don't even know which adjustments am I missing to make a good development of those images. Some blogs say that RAW images of this drone have a very strong color distortion. I have tried to find the correct adjustments to overcome that problem, and I thought that somebody could know which adjustments could help me fix that distortion.